# How to retrieve mathematical equation from MySQL using JDBC in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, itext

I want to retrieve mathematical equations from MySQL database in java and write it to a PDF file using iTextPDF.

I tried setting character encoding to UTF8 in database connection, then I retrieved data in bytes from the database, converted it into String and then added it to my document. The resultant pdf file doesn't have any mathematical symbols. Is java the culprit or iTextPdf?

```
public class MathematicalEquation {
static final String DEST = "D://Zaid/MathemaicalEquations/test101.pdf";
static final String FONT = "D://Zaid/MathematicalEquations/FreeSans.ttf";
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, DocumentException, IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DEST);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    Table table = new Table(new float[] {50,5});

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true);
    Font f = new Font(bf);

    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mySql://127.0.0.1/MathematicalProblem?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "Mobilen0");
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet myRs = null;
    myStmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    myStmt.executeQuery("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");

    myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM equations");

    byte[] imageBytes=null;
    Blob image1=null;
    ImageData imgData;
    Image image = null;
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
    byte[] equation = null;



    while(myRs.next()) {
                equation = myRs.getString("equation").getBytes("UTF-8");
                image1 = myRs.getBlob("image"); 
    }

    if(image1!=null) {
        imageBytes = image1.getBytes(1, (int) image1.length());
        imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageBytes);
        image = new Image(imgData);
    }


    String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(equation);
    String decodedEquation = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    para = new Paragraph(String.format("%s%n " , decodedEquation, f));
    cell.add(para).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    if(image1!=null) {
        cell.add(image.scaleAbsolute(100, 100))
            .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    }
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
    myRs.close();
    myStmt.close();
    myConn.close();
}
```

}

Output: 
4 x 25 ÷
5 = ?

Expected output is: 
√4 x √25 ÷ 5 = ?

Comment: Please create a www.sqlfiddle.com example.

Comment: The output is base64 of "Storedas  Question10Storedas  Question10", doesn't even resemble the expected output. So either you retrieve the wrong column, or you inserted the incorrect data. What is the data in the table row?

Comment: @k5 I selected the wrong column. This is my output: 4oiaNCB4IOKImjI1IMO3IDUgPSA/

Comment: Why are you encoding the equation to base64 and then immediately decoding it from base64?  What are you expecting that round trip to accomplish?  If ResultSet.getString doesn’t return valid characters, you need to fix the parameters of your JDBC connection.  Under no circumstances should you try to fix it anywhere else, and Base64 conversions wouldn’t help you do that anyway.

Comment: Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html, which explicitly warns: “Do not issue the query SET NAMES with Connector/J”

Comment: @VGR i removed the encoding and decoding of base64. I still get the same output in the pdf file but when i print it in console in the ide the output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The output is base64 encoded. You need to decode it first.

Add this decodedEquation to the pdf

```
String decodedEquation = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(equation), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: After adding this code the output is: âˆš4 x âˆš25 Ã· 5 = ?

Comment: How did you create you Font instance ?

Comment: @k5 static final String FONT = "D://Zaid/MathematicalEquations/FreeSans.ttf";
  BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true);
  Font f = new Font(bf);

Comment: Looks like you mixed some other encoding in there. Font definition is fine. Can you add your current code from select to `cell.add(para)`